# pear.php.net is down. How to install mirror?

Tags: php, pear

I was trying to install new packages in my PHP environment development via PEAR but as shown below:

```
File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

it seems that `php.net` is down.

I tried to setup a mirror since `us.php.net` which Digg hosts with the following command:

```
pear config-set preferred_mirror us.pear.php.net
```

which gives the following error:

```
Channel Mirror "us.pear.php.net" does not exist in your registry for channel "pear.php.net".
Attempt to run "pear channel-update pear.php.net" if you believe this mirror should exist as you may have outdated channel information.
```

Of course I can't update the channel since `php.net` is down.

Does anyone know how i should proceed?

Comment: Yeh, PHP PEAR has problems today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is down, nothing you can do except for waiting it to be up again.

Let's wait together, I cannot do several tasks due to the reason too.

Comment: Well, the files are also hosted on the `us.pear.php.net` mirror so there must be a mean to switch to the mirror even if the main site is down.

Comment: Oh, I got it, `us.pear.php.net` is just a rest/download mirror, not a full mirror. I'll wait for other answers before accepting yours, just if there is indeed something to do beside waiting.